# I need to Delete a Control inside a WrapPanel created dynamically inside another WrapPanel while in Run-Time

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

So, I have a main `WrapPanel` called "valoresPanel". When I start running I need to click the `Button` labeled "2" (below) and a `TextBox` needs to appear inside the `WrapPanel` labeled "1" thats was created in runtime.

[image: this image show how my system looks, it helps to understand]

This is my code for the "+ button" right now:

```
void novoValor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           WrapPanel wpValores = new WrapPanel();

           Button deleteValor = new Button();
           TextBox txtValor = new TextBox();

           deleteValor.Height = 25;
           deleteValor.Width = 25;
           deleteValor.Content = "X";

           txtValor.Height = 25;
           txtValor.Width = 70;
           txtValor.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 8, 0);

           wpValores.Height = 25;
           wpValores.Width = 105;

           wpValores.Children.Add(deleteValor);
           wpValores.Children.Add(txtValor);

           valoresPanel.Children.Add(wpValores);

           deleteValor.Click += deleteValor2_Click;
       }
```

So, i updated my code using only one WrapPanel per item, now i can add a item, add values and delete the item with its respective values but i cant delete a specific value, this is my code by now:

[this image will help to understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v66XN.jpg)

```
 void novoValor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;
            WrapPanel wpFather = btn.Parent as WrapPanel;
            WrapPanel wpValue = new WrapPanel();

            Button deleteValue = new Button();
            TextBox txtValue = new TextBox();

            wpValue.Height = 25;
            wpValue.Width = 105;

            deleteValue.Height = 25;
            deleteValue.Width = 25;
            deleteValue.Content = "-";

            txtValue.Height = 25;
            txtValue.Width = 70;
            txtValue.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 8, 0);

            wpValue.Children.Add(deleteValue);
            wpValue.Children.Add(txtValue);

            wpFather.Children.Add(wpValue);

            deleteValue.Click += deleteValor_Click;
        }

        void deleteValor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;
            WrapPanel panel = btn.Parent as WrapPanel;
            entradasPanel.Children.Remove(panel);
        }
```

If someone need any other information im willing to send it as fast as I can!

Comment: So, what are you having trouble with exactly? What's not working?

Comment: `valoresPanel` appears to be limited in width, otherwise the children you add to it should be laid to the right, not below it like in your picture. What contains `valoresPanel`? We really need to see what the entire visual tree looks like. Can you create a XAML representation that exhibits the problem, using all the elements that are actually in your visual tree?

Comment: And what are you doing with the input of the `TextBox` elements? How do get it? Your C# approach is wrong. You should create a `ListView` which has a `WrapPanel` as `ItemsPanel`. Then to the `ListView.ItemsSource` you bind an `ObservableCollection` of data models. By defining a `DataTemplate` for the `ListView.ItemTemplate` you can make the data items be displayed as a `TextBox` with a `Button` where the `TextBox` binds to this item's data model. By pressing the delete button you simply remove this data model from the `ObservaleColection` ( the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView`).

Comment: @andrew it´s because i created a WrapPanel using all the line space, if i decrease the width the new childrens will appear on the right, but when i click the first "x" i need it to clean the first "Entrada" and all its values("valores").

Comment: @KeithStein i need to create a new "entrada" with a space for its respective values ("valores"), when I click the first "X" button i need it to clean the "entrada" space and all its respective "valoress".

Comment: @BionicCode so, after reading your reply i had another idea that consists in: instead of creating two panels, ill create one and inside of it ill create a dynamic one where ill add all of the info, soon i´ll update it here, i believe it will be easier to solve..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my last question with the following code:

```
    void deleteValue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        WrapPanel panel = btn.Parent as WrapPanel;
        WrapPanel panelPai = panel.Parent as WrapPanel;
        panelPai.Children.Remove(panel);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a `ListView` which has a `WrapPanel` as `ItemsPanel`. Then to the `ListView.ItemsSource` you bind an `ObservableCollection` of data models. By defining a `DataTemplate` for the `ListView.ItemTemplate` you can make the data items be displayed as a `TextBox` with a `Button` where the `TextBox` binds to this item's data model. By pressing the delete button you simply remove this data model from the `ObservaleColection` ( the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView`).

**DataModel.cs**

```
class DataModel
{
  public string UserInput { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<DataModel> Items { get; set; }
  public ICommand AddItemCommand => new AsyncRelayCommand(() => this.Items.Add(new DataModel()));    
  public ICommand RemoveItemCommand => new AsyncRelayCommand((item) => this.Items.Remove(item));

  public ViewModel()
  {
    this.Items = new ObservableCollection<DataModel>();
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Add Item"
            Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}" />

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
      <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <WrapPanel Width="600" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemsPanel>

      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataModel}">
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Remove Item"
                    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}, Path=DataContext.RemoveItemCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding UserInput}" />
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: So, i updated my code using only one WrapPanel per item, now i can add a item, add values and delete the item with its respective values but i cant delete a specific value, ill update my new code above, thanks for your reply ill try it like that later.

Comment: Alright. But if you prefer a cleaner solution, that handles the data manipulation in the view model (rather than in the view's code-behind) and uses data binding to retrieve the content of the `TextBox` consider my solution. It's a simple and clean XAML approach. Creating controls using XAML is the preferred and recommended way.

Comment: So, i was trying to apply your solution but since im working with WPF i got some error messages using this code like ViewModel and DataItem not being supported..

Comment: You have to implement the classes. See my example. `ViewModel` is a class. So is `DataModel`. The `DataType` of `DataItem` is a typo and is `DataModel` instead. I corrected it.

Comment: You can copy and paste it and it should work. You may have to implement your own `ICommand` or download `AsyncRelayCommand` via selecting "NuGet Package Manager" by right clicking on the project that references this class. Then search for "AsyncRelayCommand".

Comment: ive tried to implement it for a while but got no success unfortunately, ill try to use your help for improvements then, thanks!!

Comment: i triend to copy and paste like you said but some things just dont work, they show a red line under it, like in observableCollection, or the datatemplate, maybe its my fault cause its a little bit hard to understand this, im trying to learn data binding now too

Comment: I am afraid the mistake is on your end. Never mind. When there are free squiggles there is also a yellow bulb showing up when hovering the mouse cursor over the errors. Click it and choose to add missing references. Otherwise check the error pane. It will tell you what exactly is wrong... Can you fix it?

Comment: Data binding is really important. Try to understand it and play around with it. If this is your try out project don't focus to much on finishing it but on trying out different things like [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview),  styles and templates.

Comment: The error in your XAML is the result of missing namespace qualifier _namespace:class_name_. I left it to avoid confusion and as I assumed that you know that all types need to be qualified with their namespace. So to fix this add the namespace that contains the `DataModel`class to the XAML.

Comment: sorry about my lack of knowledge, i´ve started a few days ago but i´ll try it again when i have some free time, about DataBinding thanks for the link, i´ll definitely look up for it, i´ve been using this one [DataBinding](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/introduction/)..